# Is it safe to power a PC fan (12V 0.30A) with an adjustable power adapter (3 -12V 2A) for an extended period? (8 hrs/day, 365 days/year)

Tags: fan

I bought a DIY air purifying kit that uses a PC fan to pull air through a HEPA filter. A blade broke and so the fan needs to be replaced. I want to buy a better quality fan, for example from Noctua.

Here is an example kit, though mine is slightly different:
[Air purifier fan kit](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DIY-xiaomi-Air-Purifier-Homemade-Air-Cleaner-HEPA-Filter-Remove-PM2-5-Smoke-Odor-Dust-Formaldehyde/32890425201.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.24.68c93390N5wenF&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10065_10068_10890_319_10546_317_10548_10696_453_10084_454_10083_10618_431_10307_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_53,ppcSwitch_0_ppcChannel&algo_expid=0a9c888a-6a30-4788-a55c-0a24fd6bb313-3&algo_pvid=0a9c888a-6a30-4788-a55c-0a24fd6bb313)

Adjustable power supply: 12V 2A ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078KGVZNF))

Fan: 12V 0.30A brushless

**My questions:**

1. In general, is it safe to use an adjustable power adapter on a PC fan? Conditions: the fan pulls air through a filter, runs 8 hours / day, 365 days/ year.
2. Can I use *any* PC fan with the adjustable power adapter? Or should I look for certain things when choosing a fan? The ideal fan being brushless and having a high static pressure rating. Assuming the fan is rated below 12V 2A.

[image: DIY Kit]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe.

What matters in that case is that the power supply voltage does not exceed the fan voltage (12V).

The second thing that matters is that the power supply can supply enough current to the fan, and that is also ok since your supply is rated 2A and your fan 0.3A.

When choosing a fan, you need to choose a voltage that is 12V, same as the power supply.

For static pressure, you would have to look at the fans datasheet.